# Recursive function inside of a function c++

Tags: c++, oop, class, recursion

Say I have a wrapper function that goes around some smaller recursive function. However, the wrapper, before calling the recursive function creates an object which the recursive function uses. How can I do this in c++? Do I just need to make it its own class? EDIT - I know if I can make it into a class and how to take it from there - but my question is do I need a class or can I somehow getaway without making one?

I made a generic example to clarify my question:

```
void wrapper()
{
    Object myObject;
    bool recurFun(int x)
    {
        // do some stuff with myObject
        if (some condition){return recurFun(x-1)}
        else {return true}
    }
}
```

Please ignore any basic syntax type errors, it is not a working example simply one to help get my question across to you guys. Thanks!

Comment: If the code you provided works, where is your problem? If the code you provided does not work, in what way does it behave differently than you intended?

Comment: No, it does not needs its own class.

Comment: I know I could make it work if I made a class, but I really don't want to if there is a simpler way to do (without a class).

Comment: Global object, or pass it through the parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use lambdas to get closures:

```
void wrapper()
{
    Object myObject;
    std::function<bool(int)> recurFun;
    recurFun = [&](int x) -> bool {
        // do some stuff with myObject
        if (some condition){return recurFun(x-1)}
        else {return true}
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have beaten me to this answer :)

Comment: It would be nice if SO allows favor an answer.

Comment: Wonderful - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that should come to your mind when a function needs to use something is to make it a parameter of that function. So have your recursive function accept the object as a parameter and thread it around in the recursive calls. The wrapper function will do the natural thing of setting up the object and passing it.